# Issue in configuring JPA with Spring 3 in Jboss 4.2.2 server

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa, jboss

I am facing issues in configuring JPA with Spring 3 in JBoss 4.2.2 server.

Please find the below file of persistence.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
 version="1.0">
 <persistence-unit name="TestPU">
  <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
  <jta-data-source>java:/TestDS</jta-data-source>
  <properties>
   <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
   <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
  </properties>
 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My spring-beans.xml is as below

```
 <bean id="MyAdvise" class=".......Aspect">
  <property name="persister">
         <bean id="dbPersister" class="..............DataBasePersister">
         </bean>
      </property>
 </bean>

    <bean id="localContainerEntityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
   <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
    <property name="database" value="ORACLE"/>
   </bean>
  </property>

  <property name="jpaProperties">
   <props>
    <prop key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup</prop>
   </props>
  </property>
 </bean> 

 <bean id="myTxManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="localContainerEntityManagerFactory"/>
 </bean>


 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTxManager" />
```

My *persister* bean is as follows.

```
public class DataBasePersister implements IPersister {

 private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DataBasePersister.class);

 // The Entity Manager
 @PersistenceContext
 protected EntityManager entityManager;

 @Transactional(readOnly = false)
 public void persist(Object data) {
  log.info("IN persist() call. Is the data can castable to MethodStats -->:"+(data instanceof MethodStats));
  log.info("Entity Manager instance -->:"+(entityManager));
  ----------------------
  ----------------------
  ----------------------  
 }

}
```

I am getting the following exception when the spring container creating my *persister* bean

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: JTA EntityManager cannot access a transactions
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:382)
 at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
 at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:166)
 at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
 at $Proxy147.getTransaction(Unknown Source)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:335)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:105)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
 at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
 at $Proxy141.persist(Unknown Source)
 at com.adp.sbs.aop.aspectj.SBSMethodStatsCollectorAspect.doAround(SBSMethodStatsCollectorAspect.java:63)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
 at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
 at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
 at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161)
 at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:621)
 at com.adp.sbs.aop.test.TestMethodLevelAnnotationStats$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$efbc78a8.MethodWithOneParamsAndReturnTypeAsString(<generated>)
 at com.adp.sbs.aop.test.SimpleTestServlet.testMethodAnnotations(SimpleTestServlet.java:46)
 at com.adp.sbs.aop.test.SimpleTestServlet.doPost(SimpleTestServlet.java:40)
 at com.adp.sbs.aop.test.SimpleTestServlet.doGet(SimpleTestServlet.java:33)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
 at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:179)
 at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
 at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
 at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
 at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JTA EntityManager cannot access a transactions
 at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.getTransaction(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:316)
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.DefaultJpaDialect.beginTransaction(DefaultJpaDialect.java:70)
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.beginTransaction(HibernateJpaDialect.java:57)
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:332)
```

Can you somebody please suggest me how to resolve this.

Comment: Is this using the Hibernate that's art of JBoss 4.2, or are you packaging another Hibernate JAR with the application?

Comment: I am using the Hibernate comes with Jboss 4.2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use JPA provider configured by your application server and JTA transactions, you need to obtain it from JNDI (instead of configuring it manually with `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`) and use `JtaTransactionManager` rather than `JpaTransactionManager`.

See [13.5.1.2 Obtaining an EntityManagerFactory from JNDI](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-setup-jndi) and documentation of your application server.

Comment: First of all thanks in resolvig my issue. Now I changed my configurations to fetch EntityManagerFactory from jndi and used <code>JtaTransaction</code> instead of <code>JpaTransaction</code>.       But in my service file, I need to create EntityManger every time. Because I am able to inject only EntitytManagerFactory to my service, not the Entity Manager.

Comment: @KVMKReddy: Perhaps you need to add `<context:annotation-config/>` to enable `@PersistenceContext`.